# jQuery attribute selector where value contains value in array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a bunch of list items with an attribute. I want to select only two or three of these at a time. Currently I am `split`ing a comma-separated list of ids then creating an array of selectors for jQuery to return:

```
var ids = $(this).text().split(','); //e.g. text = 1,13,27
var selectors = [];
for (var index in ids)
{
    selectors.push('.container ul.class li[data-id="'+ids[index]+'"]');
}
$(selectors.join(',')).addClass('active');
```

This appears to be quite an expensive approach for Firefox. Is there a way to optimise this so I can select any li with the data-id attribute containing any of the ids?

Something similar to the below, but selecting any of the values?

```
var ids = $(this).text().split(','); //e.g. text = 1,13,27
$('.container ul.class li[data-id~="' + ids + '"]').addClass('active');
```

[edit]

Thanks to [@Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak)'s comment I have changed my loops to:

```
var ids= $(this).text().split(',');
var length = ids.length;
for (var i=0; i<length;i++)
{
    selectors.push('.container ul.class li[data-id="'+ids[i]+'"]');
}
```

This has delivered a big improvement, but is there any more I can do?

Comment: don't use `for ... in` on arrays - it's for enumerating _object keys_, not _array indices_.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the `for ... in` for `for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)`. This has delivered a big improvement, but is there any more I can do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about:

```
var ids = "21,5,6,7,10".split(",");

// selector produced: [data-id='21'],[data-id='5'],[data-id='6'],[data-id='7'],[data-id='10']
$("[data-id='" + ids.join("'],[data-id='") + "']").addClass("active");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3MNDy/

Comment: This has given me the best performance improvement. I've altered the selector to include the div class and ul class: `var selector = '.container ul.class li[data-id="'; $(selector + ids.join('"]' + selector) + '"]').addClass('active');`

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King _This has given me the best performance improvement._ I don't think so, based on which criterion?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `filter` method:

```
$('.container ul.class li').filter(function() {
     return ids.indexOf($(this).data('id')) > -1;
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: +1 even i know its redundant but older version of IE don't support indexOf method for arrays

Comment: @roasted Yes, that's true, for _IE_ jQuery's `$.inArray` can be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
var ids = $(this).text().split(',');

$.each(ids, function(k, v){
   $('.container ul.class li[data-id="' + v + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I've tried this. It does work, but I'm trying to optimise this script to make as few dom calls/updates as possible (not explained in the question but should be). Which is why I'm creating an array of selectors and doing the one dom update at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It should be more performant to select all the elements with a `data-id` attribute once, then filter that list based on the value of the attribute:

```
var $matches = $('.container ul.class li[data-id]').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(this.getAttribute("data-id"), ids);
});

$matches.addClass('active'); // or whatever else you want to do
```

Comment: The array of ids is being converted into strings `["1","13","27"]` and I think `$.inArray` is cast checking as well so is always returning -1.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King: The return value of `getAttribute` is a string and so are the values in `ids`. I don't see why this would return -1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be more optimized approach:

```
var ids = $(this).text().split(','); //e.g. text = 1,13,27
var lis = $('.container ul.class li');
lis.filter(function() {
   return $.inArray($(this).data('id'), ids);
}).addClass('active');
```